# Problem with rsync - No incremental

Tags: linux, rsync

Got a strange problem. We have a directory with hundreds of huge log files, and I have to transfer them to a new server.

First I did : `rsync -zavh /foo/bar/logs 10.10.10.10:/`

Worked well, took an eternity. Now 2 days after, I'm trying to update. I know there's only 20 new files. So I do `rsync --dry-run -zavh /foo/bar/logs 10.10.10.10:/` first. It says it's sending incremental file list, but then try to recopied the WHOLE directory again with the new 20 files.

I've checked and the older files have the same date stamp and size.

Why rsync is not just transfering the 20 or so files that are newer ?

Comment: What filesystem is 10.10.10.10:/

Comment: Source is ext4 (RHEL 6.10) and destination is xfs (RHEL 7.8). That said, this  is the only directory that gives me that kind of behavior. The other directories (same source/destination) are sync incrementaly without problem.

Comment: Please add the `-i` flag to your run and add some of the output to your question.  It will show the reason that a file is selected for copying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Came after cutover though, but I'll keep in mind if I stumbled over that problem again.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a trailing slash on the source directory.

The first time you ran this I expect it created `/logs` on the destination, just as expected. The next time you run it, though, it will have (started to) put the source `logs` directory into the existing `/logs` directory, creating `/logs/logs`.

The solution here is to put a trailing slash on the source directory and specify the target fully

```
rsync -zavh /foo/bar/logs/ 10.10.10.10:/logs/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with, or without trailing slashes, it gives me the same list (dry-run) including the old unmodified files.

Comment: Correct destination path? Owner/group? Does `stat` show exactly the same time in source and destination?

Comment: Thanks again. Same size, some blocks small differences (202280 instead of 202288). Mostly same modify time (Modify: 2018-06-20 20:30:20.000000000 -0400 instead of Modify: 2018-06-20 20:30:20.672219155 -0400). I mean there are differences at the fraction of seconds...would that be enough ? Those were created by rsync at first run right ?

Comment: According to the man page, `rsync` only uses whole seconds for comparison (by default), so that should be fine. Can you explain what you mean about differences in the blocks please

Comment: Well stat reports : "Size: 103565566       Blocks: 202288     IO Block: 4096   regular file" on the source and : "Size: 103565566       Blocks: 202280     IO Block: 4096   regular file" on the destination. Which is odd, but maybe the different filesystem type and the size of the file maybe ?

Comment: Mmm. The number of blocks isn't an issue (that's a consequence of the filesystem). Size is good. Date is good. Might be worth running with `-vv` or even three of them to see if you can identify why it wants to recopy. Double check the target pathname